# How to slice a double cone to get a pair of parallel lines?

Tags: conic-sections

There are four possible types of degenerate conics ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic)): a point, a single straight line, a pair of intersecting lines, and a pair of parallel lines.

I am however unable to see how one can use a 2D plane to slice a double cone to get a pair of parallel lines. Googling, I'm also unable to find any image showing how this can be done and I was hoping someone here could show me (if this is indeed possible).

I did find [this decades-old discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122100135/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54756.html) claiming that the "solution" is to treat a cylinder as a "degenerate cone". Is that the correct solution?

Comment: The correct solution is, indeed, to treat the cylinder as a "degenerate cone", with its vertex "at infinity". This is not really much different than treating a parabola as an ellipse with a focus "at infinity". When you play with conics (and *projective geometry*) enough, you get used to that "at infinity" stuff.

Comment: You could also define a conic as the solution to a quadratic equation in two variables: $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ . A pair of parallel vertical lines would be, for example, $x^2-1=0$ .